# NSString to NSdate in Changes iOS 6 only

Tags: ios6, nsstring, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have a string `Apr. 20, 2013 Saturday @ 7:00 PM` and I am using below code:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
   [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMM. d, yyyy EEEE @ h:mm a"];
   NSDate *dateFromString = nil;
   dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
   [dateFormatter release];
```

and I am getting the result as `2000-01-01 13:30:00 +0000`. It is giving me wrong in iOS 6.

Comment: What is this supposed to do:  `NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];`?

Comment: (There is some sort of iOS 6 oddity with regard to date parsing, but I don't recall the details.  I'm thinking, though, that somehow skipping the EEEE might be the solution.)

Comment: @HotLicks, Yes you are correct but i need to add one more for the correct ans and i removed the EEEE.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do like this:

```
NSDate *today = [[NSDate alloc] init];
NSDateFormatter *aux = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[aux setDateFormat: @"MMM. d, yyyy EEEE @ h:mm a"];
NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"es_ES"]; // Your locale, recommended 'en_US', 'en_GB', etc...
[aux setLocale:locale];
NSString *date = [aux stringFromDate: today];
```

BTW: you have to initialize your `NSDate` variable, if you assign it to a `nil` value then probably it won't work as desired like it's happening.

**EDIT1:**
Probably you want to use this date format:

```
[dateFormat setDateFormat: @"EE, dd MMM yyyy '-' HH:mm"];
```